# Talk about 2 things that each one are one of the most (something)

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am not a native English speaker and sometime don't know what is the correct word I have to use.

> Osmium is one of the densest elements we have ever known. Iridium is one of the densest elements we have ever known.

Do I use the word correctly if I say,

> Osmium and Iridium are **two** of the densest elements we have ever known.

And is it will be incorrect if I say,

> Osmium and Iridium are **one** of the densest elements we have ever known.

Since Osmium and Iridium are two things not one, so it has to be "two of the densest..." but "two of the most (something)" doesn't sound familiar to me, so I am not sure if I use the word correctly or not. And do I have other choices if I want to mean something like this ?

Comment: I have edited the question to be better grammatically. If I have done so correctly, I believe it proper for someone else to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with saying *two of the most [adjective].* There is a group of elements which are the densest, and osmium and iridium are two of them. Obviously they are not 'one element'.

Comment: Right. But note that there's no need for personal recollection in a scientific statement. Get rid of the _we have ever_ - you people weren't there your whole lives witnessing element densities. Osmium and iridium are two of the densest elements known; that's enough, without _we_ and _ever_.

Comment: Thank you. So, it will be incorrect if I say Osmium and Iridium are one of the densest elements we have ever known. Do I understand right ?

Comment: Yes, I said so - they are two different elements, not one.

Comment: I am glad I made the correct edits; the answer and comments reflect what I would have written myself.